# Storing data of rich text box to database with formatting

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, richtextbox

I am new at wpf and I want to store the data of the rich text box along with its formatting (Italic, colored, Bold..)  into a database (Mysql).
currently when i save the data, formatting is ignored. 
in addition, it shows all the text in the same line when i load it back to the rich text box from the database. 
Looking forward to your help and suggestions!

```
public void save()
    {  

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();      
        string richText = new TextRange(rt1.Document.ContentStart,  rt1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

        string s = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(richText); 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", s);           
        command.CommandText = "insert into proc_tra (procedures) values (@s)";
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

public void load()

    {   MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select * from proc_tra where id_pt=4";
        rt1.Document.Blocks.Clear();            
        conn.Open();            
        MySqlDataReader dr;
        dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        string k="";           
        while (dr.Read())
        {              
            k += dr["procedures"].ToString();
        }
        var p = new Paragraph();
        var run = new Run();
        run.Text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(k);
        p.Inlines.Add(run);
        rt1.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
    }
```

Comment: hope [this](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c7529/Saving-Rich-Edit-Control-Text-to-SQL-Server.htm) helps

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get the formatted text that will be saved in the db:

```
string rtfText; //string to save to db
TextRange tr = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
    rtfText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

To restore the formatted text retrieved from the db:

```
string rtfText= ... //string from db
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtfText);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

You can also use XAML format instead, using DataFormats.XAML on load an save.

Comment: Dosent work dear, Shows richtextbox doesnt have any definition called Document.

Comment: @SharadAg. This is for WPF, not WinForms.

Comment: **If you are receiving the error**                                                             "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."       Note that he is using the "richTextBox" as a variable and not the class.            This means you need the following code to allow the TextRange to work.         'RichTextBox richTextBox = default(RichTextBox);'                             Great Solution btw, thumbs up.

Answer (score 3):

For WinForm applications, use richTextBox1.rtf, rather than richTextBox.Text

Comment: This thread is for WPF. Thus your answer here is out of the thread scope. However your answer could be 'valid' if you have shared a working alternative for WinForms. That would help people looking for a WinForms solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox();
string richText = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

Then, when going to save it to MySQL, you can build your query like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO blah VALUES ('" + HTTPUtility.HtmlEncode(richText) +  "');
```

This will ensure that your content stays formatted correctly.

Finally when you perform your select to load the content back into the RichTextBox take the string you get and use:

```
HTTPUtility.HtmlDecode(selectedDataFromMySQL);
```

or, more completely:

```
richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(HTTPUtility.HtmlDecode(selectedDataFromMySQL);
```

While I haven't done this in a while myself, I believe there is an extension for the WPF and the control that includes a Text property so that may prove useful as well.

Comment: thx for the answer but ‘HttpUtility’ does not exist in the current context even if I add system.web

Comment: I 've added reference to System.Web and Used using System.Web but still not working

Comment: Make sure your project is not targeting one of the Client Profile frameworks in your project properties.

Comment: I already checked and I am targeting .Net framework 4.5 (not the client profile)

Comment: Since you are using .NET 4.5 you can swap out the HTTPUtility.HtmlEncode/Decode for this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx

Comment: thx again for your help, I swaped to Webutility, I can save data to mysql but when i load it back still no formatting.
I've updated my post with my code.

Comment: maybe the (selectedDataFromMySQL).tostring() with the datareader is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Public Function BacklashInsert(ByVal mrtfdat As String) As String

```
    'insert / into data to keep format/ in mysql record
    Dim n As Integer = mrtfdat.Length
    Dim nrtf As String = ""
    Dim mchrasc As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
        mchrasc = Asc(mrtfdat.Substring(i))
        If mchrasc = 92 Then
            nrtf = nrtf & Chr(42)
        Else
            nrtf = nrtf & Chr(mchrasc)
        End If
    Next
    Return nrtf
End Function
Public Function Backlaskrip(ByVal mrtfdat As String) As String
    Dim n As Integer = mrtfdat.Length
    Dim nrtf As String = ""
    Dim mchrasc As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
        mchrasc = Asc(mrtfdat.Substring(i))
        If mchrasc = 42 Then
            nrtf = nrtf & Chr(92)
        Else
            nrtf = nrtf & Chr(mchrasc)
        End If
    Next
    Return nrtf
End Function
```

I did it in VB that is the code I use

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would greatly improve the quality of your answer if you could explain why your code works. See [answer] for more information.