# Why doesn't my WPF RichTextBox keep the Superscript and Subscript data after saving and loading it again?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

I'm kinda new here so I apologize in advance in case I'm not asking this question properly.

Currently, I'm working on a small TextEditor project in **WPF**, **C#** and **.Net 4.5**, but I recently found an issue that I can't seem to overcome. For some reason, the RichTextBox that gets converted to Rtf for saving proposes doesn't save the `BaselineAlignmentProperty` (superscripts & subscripts), which should be possible (according to the Rtf 1.5 spec: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm subscripting & superscripting are supported (\sub ; \super & \nosupersub)).

Code I'm using to convert the RichTextBox to Rtf and to load the Rtf to a RichTextBox ([Storing data of rich text box to database with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983278/storing-data-of-rich-text-box-to-database-with-formatting)):

```
    public static string ToRtf(RichTextBox RichText)
    {
        string RtfText;
        TextRange Text = new TextRange(RichText.Document.ContentStart, RichText.Document.ContentEnd);
        using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Text.Save(MS, DataFormats.Rtf);
            RtfText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MS.ToArray());
        }

        return RtfText;
    }

    public static void LoadRtfData(RichTextBox TextBox, string RtfText)
    {
        byte[] Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RtfText);

        using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(Data))
        {
            TextRange Text = new TextRange(TextBox.Document.ContentStart, TextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            Text.Load(MS, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
    }
```

Also, changing the DataFormat to `Xaml` or `XamlPackage` (as described here as a possibility: http://umaranis.com/2010/11/29/save-and-load-richtextbox-content-in-wpf/) results in a crash.

Code I'm using to change the `BaselineAligmentProperty` on the selected text at `MyTextBox`:

```
MyTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.BaselineAlignmentProperty, BaselineAlignment.Bottom/*BaselineAligment.Subscript doesn't work either*/);
```

What should I do to make my RichTextBox Rtf include the BaselineAlignment data when saving/loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work by changing the DataFormat to Xaml.